# Не могу получить файл из формы

Tags: form, express, fetch, multer

Приветствую обитателей форума. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я пытаюсь с клиента отправить содержимое формы, в том числе картинку из `<input type="file" id="project_data_upload" name="project_data_upload" accept="image/*" multiple/>`

### Вот здесь небольшой фрагмент клиентской части.

```
<form id="review-form" >
  <input type="file" id="project_data_upload" name="project_data_upload" accept="image/*" multiple/>                            
  </form>

<script>
    const sendReviewForm = () => {
            let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('review-form'));
            Array.from(document.getElementById("project_data_upload").files).forEach( (file) => {
                formData.append('project_data_upload', file);
                })
                                
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/review-upload', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=something',
                                        
                        }
                    })

            .then(response => console.log(response))
      }
                            
  </script>

<button onclick="sendReviewForm()">Отправить</button>
```

### И серверная часть.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'avatars/' })
const cors = require('cors')



app.post('/review-upload', upload.array('project_data_upload'), function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.files, req.body)
    
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.status(200).json({message: "Good message"})
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server started on port 5000"))
```

В чем проблема? Если я использую `upload.array('project_data_upload')` вывод будет таким `[] [Object: null prototype] {}`
А если upload.single('project_data_upload') вывод такой `undefined [Object: null prototype] {}`

Как мне получить содержимое `req.file` или `req.files`?

Comment: Для проекта используется `multer@1.4.3` так как в версии `multer@1.4.5` вылазят ошибки, на подобие `Error: Unexpected end of form`